# In Java, can I make an instance of a subclass "based on" an instance of the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say I have a class `Child` which extends another class, `Parent`:

```
public class Parent {
    private String value;
    public Parent() { }
    public String getValue() { return this.value; }
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value; }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private String anotherValue;
    public Child() { super(); }
    public String getAnotherValue() { return this.anotherValue; }
    public void setAnotherValue() { this.anotherValue = anotherValue; }
}
```

Now, for any instance `parent` of the class `Parent` and want to construct an instance `child` of class `Child` such that the object `child` extends the object `parent`, i.e., in this case, `child.getValue().equals(parent.getValue())`.

One way to do this, is to add a constructor to `Child` as follows:

```
    public Child(Parent parent) {
        this.setValue(parent.getValue());
    }
```

This does the job, but it can be fastidious if the superclass is more complicated, and, more importantly, as the superclass evolves over time, this constructor should constantly be updated, which can be forgotten, to more or less disastrous effects.

It can also be done with reflection, which is probably an overkill.

So **I wonder if there is any Java-native way to do exactly this: create an instance of the subclass and copy all the properties of an instance the superclass.** It is in a way the inverse of casting.

Comment: Natively, I would do it with reflection. On a real project, I would use dozer (which actually does it by reflection but better than if you did it by yourself)

Comment: what is your use case for this?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing why you need this, but maybe you could use upper-bounded wild cards for this? For example if you have a method that takes a List<Parent> and you want to change it to also take lists of children you can rewrite the parameter as List<? extends Parent>. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"I wonder if there is any Java-native way to do exactly this: create an instance of the subclass and copy all the properties of an instance the superclass"**

Nothing comes to mind, but you should think a little harder about what you're trying to do. You could add a copy constructor in Parent or use clone.

```
class Parent {
    String type;
    public Parent(Parent p) { this.type = p.type; }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(Parent p) { super(p); }
}
```

Or you could create a static `newInstance()` method in Child

```
class Parent {
    String type;
    public copyInstance(Parent p) { this.type = p.type; }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static Child newInstance(Parent p) { Child c = new Child(); c.copyInstance(p); return c; }
 }
```

Or other things like that. In short, I have to ask why you are asking `Child` to know about `Parent`?

Comment: To ask the subclass `Child` to know about the superclass `Parent`, was exactly what I was trying to _avoid_! And both your solutions work. (By the way, I would add `extends Parent` in the declaration of `class Child` if I could edit your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is **no build-in support** to do it automatically. When you want to copy field values, the common pattern is to create **copy-constructors** both for `Parent` and `Child` class:

```
public class Parent {
    public int a;
    public String s;

    public Parent(Parent src) {
        this.a = src.a;
        this.s = src.s;
    }

    // +init-constructor
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public double d;

    public Child(Child src) {
        super(src);
        this.d = src.d;
    }

    // +init-constructor
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to copy fields only from super-class `Parent` I would add another copy-constructor which copies only parent fields:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    // +fields

    // +copy-constructor Child(Child src)

    public Child(Parent src) {
        super(src);
    }

    // +init-constructor
}
```

So the right constructor will be chosen by the type of the instance.

```
Parent p = new Parent(1, "a");
Child c = new Child(1, "a", 2.0);

Child pCopy = new Child(p);
Child cCopy = new Child(c);
```

Note, you can also explicitly up-cast child instance to parent type in case, you want to copy only parent fields from the child:

```
Child c = new Child(1, "a", 2.0);
Child  pCopy  = new Child((Parent) c);
```

If you want to copy fields to already constructed child, I would do something like what you see in answer of @KarlNicholas.

Comment: So, for the subclass, rather than a copy constructor, I need a constructor like `public Child(Parent src) { super(src); }`, right? (Because I only have an instance of `Parent` on the basis of which I want to construct an instance of `Child`.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a shortcoming of java. Basically we are talking about cloning here. Java does not have a robust object cloning mechanism built into the language. You have to use hacks like serialization/deserialization.

What you can do in your case:

```
class Child {
 private Parent parent;

public Child(Parent p) {
 // reference - carefully! If Parent were immutable, this would be safe, otherwise, you need a copy constructor
 this.parent = p;
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the case on hand, I don't have the option to go for _composition over inheritance_, otherwise, this would be a very viable solution...

Comment: You should always try to favor composition over inheritance where possible in your design. But yes, here is a classic example of inheritance.